# Generate .gcno and .gcda files at different direcotry using .make and CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, linux, code-coverage, gcov, lcov

I want to generate the .gcno and .gcda files at another directory but I need help to to proceed with that using CMakeLists.txt and .make files

I tried with POST_BUILD it didn't work and I'm confused how to use GCOV_PREFIX , If you have any better solution please help

Comment: Please show a [mre] of what you've tried and the problems you're having with it